# How to correctly enable a service on a CentOs 7 machine using systemctl enable command?

Tags: linux, centos, services, centos-7, systemctl

I am not a sysadministrator (I am a software developer) but this time I have to install some agents on some CentOS machines that have to be monitored by Wazuh (a SIEM software) and I have the following doubt. After a successful installation of the agent via YUM I have to enable the service related to this Wazuh agent.

Then I have to enable the **wazuh-agent** service performing the following command:

```
[adminuser@my-machine ~]$ systemctl enable wazuh-agent
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files ===
Authentication is required to manage system service or unit files.
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 1.  Cloud User (centos)
 2.  adminuser
 3.  user2
```

The problem is that performing the command it is asking to me with what user I wanto to enable the service (requiring user authentication).

On this machine I have defined 3 users:

- **centos**: it is an user with administrative privileges that was used to perform the first access to this machine via SSH and from here it was used to create the other 2 users.
- **adminuser**: it is my admin user (and have SSH access). It have administrative privileges.
- **user2** it is a second admin user that have not SSH access. It have administrative privileges but it is used by another person working on this machine that is not involved in this Wazuh agent activity.

So what is the best choice? I was thinking to use my personal admin user (adminuser) but I am not sure that it is the best choice.

Another doubt is: with this command I am enabling this **wazuh-agent** service. What happens if the machine is rebooted? After the reboot this service will automatically startup or it is needed a manual start?

Answer (score 0):

When managing system services, like the wazuh-agent, it must be done with root privileges, since the command was not run using sudo it is asking you to select which admin user you can provide credentials for.
All options are valid as they will run the command as root, so select any for which you have the credentials.
Regarding your second question, after enabling the service it will start automatically every time the system is rebooted.